# When was critical mass suspected?

Tags: radioactivity, atomic-weapons

The various famous experiments at Los Alamos where the experimenter would dangerously push two masses of plutonium or uranium near each other and observe increased activity -- was such a phenomenon observed with other radioactive substances many years before discovery of even the neutron?

Or is it possible that the kind of radioactive materials did not work this way? Or they did not have enough of the element to see it happen? I read that radium has a critical mass but maybe they never tried this experiment?

But would not it have been observed that 1 gm of Ra was more active than a half of a gram or is that not even the case?

Comment: For small (such as a gram) quantities the loss of neutrons from the sample prevents it from going critical. Hence needing a ‘critical’ mass. The plutonium ball for Trinity was warm to the touch, but not critical.

Comment: I do vaguely recall an unhappy accident somewhere with a technician accidentally getting two bad things toooo close together, ... and not only getting a bit of a show, but getting a lethal dose of radiation. Maybe at Los Alamos?

Comment: @paulgarrett perhaps you're thinking of this? Hollywood's version [here](https://youtu.be/AQ0P7R9CfCY) or [here](https://youtu.be/hh89h8FxNhQ) and Wikipedia's [Demon Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_core)

Comment: perhaps somewhat related in Earth Science SE: [Natural nuclear explosions](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2147/6031)

Comment: @uhoh, ah, yes, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You certainly refer to Manhattan physicist Louis Slotin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Slotin

Comment: I do not. Critical Mass was well understood prior to this scientist.

Answer (score 2):

Radium can't have a critical mass as it doesn't emit neutrons during decay.

See:
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Decay-chain-of-radium-226-showing-the-main-radionuclides-with-the-type-of-radioactive_fig4_263672557